# SQL Server Service Account on Windows Server 2016 Workgroup Cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, installation, clustering

I am trying to install SQL Server 2016 failover clustered instance on a Windows Server 2016 workgroup cluster. I have tried using a virtual account and also a local account that exists on both nodes.

Both types of account throw the error:

> The specified Service Account is not valid. Please provide a domain account to continue

What type of account should I use for installing SQL Server 2016 failover clustered instance on a Windows Server 2016 workgroup cluster?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that only Availability Groups are supported on workgroup clusters in 2016. SQL FCI is not supported. You must use a domain.